# writeToDisk with create-react-app not displaying work files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to configure webpack in my react app so that during development, the files are visible in the `dist` folder (or wherever).

So I tried `react-app-rewired` with the following config

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.devServer = {
        devMiddleware: {
            writeToDisk: true
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  I've been looking for how to make `writeToDisk` work, and it seems to have changed at some point, because I can't find anything online that works.

How can I get `writeToDisk` to work so that it writes the hot-reload files to a visible folder when running `react-scripts start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up going with [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) instead, which worked.

`craco.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost }) => {
        devServerConfig.devMiddleware.writeToDisk = true;
        return devServerConfig;
    },
};
```